# Are BigIntegers safe?

Tags: android, kotlin, security, biginteger, storing-data

I use BigIntegers to store my public and private keys for RSA encryption. Lately I found out that Strings are not safe to store passwords due to them being immutable. Do BigIntegers have the same volnurability?

Currently im refactoring my code so user keys are stored in char arrays instead of Strings when sent from one part of the app to another. I need to know if making BigInteger objects from these char arrays is safe for the users data, or if I need to change that part of my app's functionality as well.

Comment: As the documentation clearly states, BigIntegers are immutable. In fact, [it is **the very first word**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger) of the text description: *Immutable arbitrary-precision integers. All operations...*

Comment: I think you misunderstood something.  A data structure being immutable doesn't mean its unsafe to hold a password or other secure data in.  Mutability, in the general case, provides no additional security.  I'd suggest posting where you read that, either the source is wrong or you missed a LOT of context.

Comment: Related: "Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make an argument for preferring `byte[]` over `BigInteger` for the same reason that `char[]` might be preferred over `String`.

For background, you should read [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881376/4618331) explaining why some people recommend using `char[]` rather than `String` for storing passwords. The short version is that arrays, being mutable, can be overwritten after use. In theory this immediately removes the sensitive data from memory. Meanwhile, strings are only removed from memory by the garbage collector, which might not run immediately. This means that the value sits around in memory for a while, which may or may not be a problem.

Like a `String`, a `BigInteger` is an object that contains an array which it prevents you from mutating. That means you can't clear out the array yourself, and have to wait for the garbage collector to free it.

If you think this is a concern, it would make sense to store your keys in byte arrays and explicitly overwrite the arrays with zeros (or any other data) after use. As for whether it's really important, I defer to the existing answers and comments in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881376/4618331).

Answer (score 0):

But wait you are asking about the security of storing the keys when "sent from one part of the app to another" and also you are saying about "I use BigIntegers to store my public and private keys for RSA encryption".

But this is not the most secure way to do it, the best way will be access the keys directly from the [Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) in place where it is needed, do not store them in memory and transfer between app parts.

Except it is not feasible for any reason I would suggest to do it that way instead of storing it in BigIntegers or any other data structure and transferring within the app.